# $O_{p', p}(G) =\cap C_{G}(H /K )$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ b e a group and let $p$ be a prime number. Then $O_{p', p}(G) =\cap C_{G}(H /K )$, where $H /K$ ranges over all principal factors of G with $p | |H /K |$.

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you are looking for a proof: page 686 of Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen* Satz VI.5.4.b (and IV.4.4 really). Doerk-Hawkes have the module theoretic proof, but it is spread out a bit and I think only works for p-solvable groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof written out. One direction using the nilpotent residual, and the other uses normal $p$-complements, but these are equivalent definitions of $p$-nilpotent.

**Proposition:** A normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup centralizes every $p$-chief factor.

*Proof:* Let $H/K$ be a $p$-chief factor of the finite group $G$, and let $N$ be a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$. Let $\newcommand{\nilres}[1]{\gamma_\infty\left({#1}\right)}\nilres{N}$ be the intersection of the lower central series of $N$. Since $N$ is $p$-nilpotent, $\nilres{N}$ is a $p'$-subgroup. Notice that $X=K(H \cap \nilres{N})$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K \leq X \leq H$. Since $H/K$ is a chief factor, that means that either $X=H$ or $X=K$. However, $X/K \cong (H \cap \nilres{N}) / (K \cap \nilres{N})$ is a $p'$-group, so $X \neq H$. Hence $X=K$. Now consider $Y=K[H,N]$; again $Y=K$ or $Y=H$. If $Y=K$, then $[H,N] \leq K$ and by definition $N$ centralizes $H/K$. However, if $Y=H$, then $Y=K[H,N] = K[Y,N] = K[ K[H,N],N ] = K [H,N,N]$. Moreover, this process can be repeated $Y=K[H,N,N] = K[Y,N,N] = K[H,N,N,N,N]$, etc.  Notice that $[H,N] \leq N$ since $N$ is normal, so $[H,N,N,\ldots,N]=[[H,N],N, \ldots,N] \leq [N,N,\ldots,N]$ and so $[H,N] \leq Y=K[H,N,\ldots,N] \leq K(H \cap \nilres{N}) = X =K$ and $N$ centralizes $H/K$. $\square$

In particular, $O_{p',p}(G)$ centralizes every $p$-chief factor. I didn't see how to prove it directly, but this means that every subnormal $p$-nilpotent subgroup centralizes every $p$-chief factor.

**Proposition:** If a subgroup centralizes every $p$-chief factor, then that subgroup is $p$-nilpotent.

**Lemma:** If a group centralizes all of its own $p$-chief factors, then that group is $p$-nilpotent.

*Proof:* (Huppert, IV.4.4 page 424, $c\implies a$) Let $G$ be a finite group that centralizes all of its $p$-chief factors. Let $H$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then $G/H$ also centralizes all of its $p$-chief factors, so by induction $G/H$ is $p$-nilpotent. Let $L/H$ be a normal $p$-complement of $G/H$. If $H$ is a $p'$-group, then $L$ is also a normal $p$-complement of $G$, so we may assume $p$ divides $[H:1]$. Hence $G$ centralizes $H$, and $H$ has order $p$. Also $H$ is a central Sylow $p$-subgroup of $L$, so by Schur–Zassenhaus, $L=H \times M$ for a $p'$-subgroup $M$. $M$ is clearly normal in $G$, and is a $p$-complement. Hence $G$ is $p$-nilpotent. $\square$

<sub><sup>(Note to Jack: $L$ had to be chosen to be the normal $p$-complement, not just the nilpotent residual in order to get the induction to work, since it is possible for the hypercenter to be contained in the nilpotent residual.)</sup></sub>

*Proof of the proposition:* (Huppert, VI.5.4.b page 686) Let $N$ be a subgroup of the finite group $G$ such that $N$ centralizes every $p$-chief factor of $G$. Let $1=G_0 < \ldots < G_n = G$ be a chief series of $G$, and consider $N_i = G_i \cap N$. The $N_i$ forms a normal series for $N$, so it can be refined to a chief series of $N$. Let $H/K$ be a chief factor of $N$. By Jordan–Hölder we may assume $N_i \leq K < H \leq N_{i+1}$ without affecting its order or centrality. If $H/K$ is a $p$-chief factor, then $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is a $p$-chief factor, and so too is $G_{i+1}/G_i$. Hence $N$ centralizes $G_{i+1}/G_i$, so $[N,G_{i+1}] \leq G_i$. So $$[N,H] \leq [N,N_{i+1}] \leq [N,G_{i+1}] \cap N \leq G_i \cap N = N_i \leq K$$
Hence $N$ centralizes $H/K$, and thus all of its $p$-chief factors. By the lemma, $N$ is $p$-nilpotent. $\square$

**Proposition:** The intersection of the centralizers of the $p$-chief factors of $G$ is $O_{p',p}(G)$.

*Proof:* The product of two subnormal $p$-nilpotent subgroups is a subnormal $p$-nilpotent subgroup (as in [Does the class of soluble groups whose $p$-length is $\leq 1$ for all $p$ form a saturated Fitting formation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414605/does-the-class-of-soluble-groups-whose-p-length-is-leq-1-for-all-p-form-a/415012#415012)), so there is a unique largest subnormal $p$-nilpotent subgroup, $F_p$, and $F_p$ is clearly characteristic in $G$. $O_{p'}(F_p)$ is characteristic in $F_p$, so $O_{p'}(F_p) \leq O_{p'}(G)$ and so $O_{p'}(F_p) = F_p \cap O_{p'}(G)$. $$F_pO_{p'}(G)/O_{p'}(G) \cong F_p/(F_p \cap O_{p'}(G)) = F_p/O_{p'}(F_p)$$ is a normal $p$-group, so $F_pO_{p'}(G)/O_{p'}(G) \leq O_p(G/O_{p'}(G)) = O_{p',p}(G)/O_{p'}(G)$ and $F_p \leq O_{p',p}(G)$. However, $O_{p',p}(G)$ is a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$, so $O_{p',p}(G) \leq F_p$. Hence $F_p = O_{p',p}(G)$ is the largest subnormal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$. By the first proposition, $F_p$ centralizes every $p$-chief factor. By the second proposition, the intersection of the centralizers of the $p$-chief factors is a (clearly normal) $p$-nilpotent group. Hence $F_p$ is the intersection of the centralizers of the $p$-chief factors. $\square$